# Change the default value of XElement at runtime in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I change the default value of the following XElement in C# using LINQ:

```
<Automobile>
  <MainBlock>Car</MainBlock>
  <Name>Audi</Name>
  <Value> type="System.Double" min="0" max="100" default="50" resolution="1.0" unit=""</Value>
</Automobile>
```

The default value is 50. I want to change it to 20.

Comment: What did you try? What is working, what is not?

Comment: That's an attribute. And the question xml is not well-formed. It's missing the closing > of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **LINQ to XML** implementation.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Automobile>
          <MainBlock>Car</MainBlock>
          <Name>Audi</Name>
          <Value type='System.Double' min='0' max='100' default='50'></Value>
        </Automobile>");
    
    xdoc.Element("Automobile").Element("Value").Attribute("default").SetValue("20");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have lot of solutions to do that. One solution:

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(@"
        <Automobile>
          <MainBlock>Car</MainBlock>
          <Name>Audi</Name>
          <Value type=""System.Double"" min=""0"" max=""100"" default=""50"" resolution=""1.0"" unit=""""></Value>
        </Automobile>");

        XmlNode sNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/Automobile/Value");
        XmlAttribute defautAttribute = sNode.Attributes["default"];

        if(defautAttribute != null)
            defautAttribute.Value = "20";
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this using LINQ?

Comment: no pure linq but you could use linq to xml